# Click one div to hide a different div

Tags: jquery

There's a lot of tutorials about hide/show functions in jQuery but can't find any regarding my issue.  I'm not new to programming, jquery is a first for me.

I would like it when a user clicks on "link 1" etc...it hides the word "hide me" below.  Currently it partially works, but it only hides the actual link...not the "hide me" word.  I know it's to do with a selector...but not sure where to put the selector in.

Thanks.

[Simple js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x11sy4je/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//user clicks on link
    $('a').click(function(){
         //hides the word below link but doesn't work
        $(this).hide();
    });


});
```

I've tried

```
 $(this).hide("panel");
```

and

```
  $("panel", this).hide();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to hide the entire clicked `.column` or just the link and the `.box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$(this).hide();
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().next('.box').hide();
```

`$(this)` is hiding what you're clicking

Answer (score 3):

Its not working because, when you say $(this) it will take object of clicked element only and that's `anchor` tag:

use this:

```
$(this).closest("div").hide();
```

Instead of

```
$(this).hide();
```

**Help your self:**
try:

```
console.log($(this));
```

//This will show what does that `$(this)` take:

**Update:**

Based, on your html structure, You can use something like this:

```
$(this).parent().next().hide()
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
   
         $(this).parent().next().hide();
    });
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="main">
   
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
     <p><a href="#" title="Click me!">Link 1</a></p>
    
     <div class="box">
      <p>Hide me</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
     <p><a href="#" title="Click me!">Link 2</a></p>
    
     <div class="box">
      <p>Hide me</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
     <p><a href="#" title="Click me!">Link 3</a></p>
    
     <div class="box">
      <p>Hide me </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it hides both of them.  I only want the word below it hidden.

Comment: So you want that link to be visible ?

Comment: @MokshShah clarified in comments, can you update your answer to it

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$(this).closest('.column').find(".box").hide();
```

Comment: The parent of the anchor is a paragraph tag

Comment: Ok forgot that one. Then closest is better. (parent().parent() isn't pretty)

Answer (score 1):

please look at what panel stands for.
in this

```
$("panel").hide();
```

you are trying to hide all tags that aare panel 
try using id

```
$("#panel").hide();
```

or class name

```
$(".panel").hide();
```

or if this is a child node of "this"
read in
https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `closest` function and hide `children`s with `.box` class. [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x11sy4je/3/) based on your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.column').children('.box').hide();
    });  
});
```